# Blocking X-forwarded-For IP in fail2ban?

Tags: firewall, reverse-proxy, fail2ban

I am using a reverse proxy in front of my web-server. In the web server I installed fail2ban and want to use it to monitor logs and block bad ip.

I am using nginx with the http realip module. But AFAIK fail2ban would still just block the direct(remote addr) IP. How can I make it block the X-forwarded-For IP instead?

And if possible, I would want it to block the remote addr IP if X-forwarded-For header is not present.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by this?

Comment: Like in the blog post http://2levelsabove.com/how-to-secure-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban/. But need to use X-forwarded-For, since cannot install fail2ban in the reverse proxy.

Comment: So the question becomes: can you get nginx to log that header in its log files?